# How to extract solution values "x" if solution is obtained using ReachabilityAnalysis.jl package?

Tags: julia, interval-arithmetic

I am solving a differential equation (with an initial condition in an interval) using ReachabilityAnalysis.jl package in Julia as,

```
prob = @ivp(x' = f(x), x(0) ∈ X0, dim=1)
sol = solve(prob, alg=TMJets21a(abstol=1e-18), T=15)
```

I wish to get an array containing "x" values, but when I am getting values like this

```
TaylorModelReachSet
  55.0 + 5.0 x₁ + ( 44.9801344648411 - 4.990972005107259 x₁ - 0.0024613652164294903 x₁²) t + ( - 22.449459189998198 + 2.4688376478960143 x₁ + 0.010727058992613947 x₁²) t² + ( 7.40324329161496 - 0.757126031600233 x₁ - 0.03224951488485455 x₁²) t³ + ( - 1.702781535410468 + 0.04388098980804231 x₁ + 0.08253929478277094 x₁²) t⁴ + ( 0.07895091288058795 + 0.2882499345694954 x₁ - 0.1908707483937028 x₁²) t⁵ + ( 0.43218402721400556 - 0.6203143736740161 x₁ + 0.4098322353914475 x₁²) t⁶ + ( - 0.7971949696667339 + 1.141845422435601 x₁ - 0.8306607029702969 x₁²) t⁷ + ( 1.2840090159806252 - 2.0106344691518556 x₁ + 1.6070995456266788 x₁²) t⁸ + [-2.21465e-07, 2.51483e-07]
[0, 0.00263234]
```

Could you please help, how can I get an array containing "x" values like this

```
x = [ [1,2], [4,8], ....... [23, 45] ]
```

Thank you

Comment: It's hard to answer this question as it stands - the code you've provided doesn't run (presumably it needs `using ReachabilityAnalysis` at least, but what's `f`? What's `X0`?). Also what are "x" values?

Comment: Dear @NilsGudat, I have just copied and pasted the example shown here https://juliareach.github.io/ReachabilityAnalysis.jl/dev/generated_examples/LotkaVolterra/ . My problem is to get solution set in array form so that I can apply mathematical functions such as "log", "sine" etc. to the solution set. If you have any solution of this problem, please let me know.